# LCOV does not work with new Xcode 5.1

Tags: ios, code-coverage, xcode5.1, lcov

I am using LCOV to get the code coverage for my iOS app but its not working with Xcode 5.1 anymore. It used to writ with older Xcode.

So i googled a little bit and found this:https://github.com/jonreid/XcodeCoverage which seems to work but doesn't include all my classes and functions. 
Just FYI i did not add any code in exclude data() so its happening by itself.

Please help me get this working.

Thanks,